# Trying to prove $ |f(0) | \leq a$ when $f(a)=0$ for a bounded holomorphic function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

Suppose we have an holomorphic function $f$ such that $ |f(z) | \leq 1$ for all $z$ and suppose $f(a)=0$ ( for example $a=1/2$). I am trying to prove that $ |f(0) | \leq a$. I have tried taking the Taylor series for which the fisrt coefficient is $f(0)$ but I got nowhere with that.

Comment: Are you aware of Liouville's theorem?

Comment: Or are the assumptions all for $z$ in the unit disk?

Comment: take a look at this : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

assuming a is a postive real number

by Liouville's theorem $f(z) = f(a) = 0\;\; \forall z$ so $|f(a)| = 0 \leq a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question is about functions on the unit disk $D=\{z:|z|\le 1\}$:

Use the Möbius transformation $h:D\to D$, $h(z)=\frac{z-a}{\bar a z-1}$ to map $h(a)=0$, $h(0)=a$. Set $g(z)=f(h(z))$
so that $g(0)=f(a)=0$. Then $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ can be holomorphically extended to $z=0$.

Now observe that  $|\frac{g(z)}{z}|<1$ on $S^1=\partial D$ and use the maximum principle.